# Is there an easy way to remember the ring axioms?

Tags: ring-theory

I'm working on a problem that asks me to prove a set is a ring. I have to look up the axioms to prove it...

I was curious, is there an easy way to remember the ring axioms, so that you can avoid having to look them up?

---

The best way I have so far, is simply remembering that there are 4 axioms for addition, and 4 for multiplication.

Comment: If you're used to groups, then it might be easier to remember the addition axioms as saying that $R$ under addition is required to be an abelian group.

Comment: Have you tried remembering them by their names?

Comment: associative, commutative, identity, inverse - right, good point.

Comment: I used to remember them as possible operations on matrices: if a $+,\,\times$ property works for matrices, then it must hold for rings.

Comment: (1)Turn your whole body into the punch. If your feet are slow, (most people have slow feet at first) you will find that punching a little slower actually hits harder than punching faster. So in other words, punch as fast as your body can turn so you won’t sacrifice power. Again, use your whole body instead of just the arms to punch. (2)Throw short hooks, short uppercuts, and short rights but long jabs. (3)You don’t always have to throw one knockout punch after another. Combo light and hard punches and use head movement to fake out your opponent.

Comment: Addition is an abelian group, multiplication is a monoid, and left- and right-distributivity.  If you can't remember which group axioms a monoid has, just think of matrix multiplication as a prototype (associative, not commutative, identity, no inverse).

Comment: The best way is:  read axioms 5 times.

Comment: Maybe there are two ways: (1) to write out the axioms 5 times; and (2) know enough examples of rings, commutative and noncommutative, as well as of nonrings (like $2\mathbb Z$).

Comment: If you're more used to fields, you can think of a ring as almost a field, but not quite as nice. I find that thinking this way and thinking about how far a particular ring is away from being a field also helps me remember the hierarchy of ring axioms (integral domains, PIDs, unital, commutative, etc.).

Comment: It comes with practice. Your instructor probably assigned you this problem precisely so that you need to look up the axioms once, twice, three times... Until in the end you don't need to look them up anymore.

Comment: After 5 times of reading I understood Will Jagy's joke ... (guess what I think of when I hear "ring" or "group" in everyday life).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, I should have picked a quote with the word boxing somewhere. Many types of fighting instruction (such as military) would not use the word ring in any way. I will do better next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A ring is a *fusion* of two very basic structures, namely an abelian group (4 axioms) and a monoid (2 axioms), compatible via distributive laws (2 axioms).

"I'm working on a problem that asks me to prove a set is a ring." - This doesn't mean that you have to verify all ring axioms. In fact, there are many "basic" rings and constructions with rings and often the task is only to realize that something is a subring of such a basic ring. In order to check for a subring, we only have to check:

- Is $0$ contained? Is $1$ contained?
- Is the subset closed under $+$ and $-$?
- Is the subset closed under $*$?

All the other ring axioms are inherited automatically from the ring "above". For example, for any space $D$, the set $\{f : D \to \mathbb{R} : f \text{ continuous}\}$ is a subring of the "basic" ring of all functions $D \to \mathbb{R}$ (with pointwise operations) because of calculus facts about continuous functions: Constant functions are continuous, and continuous functions are closed under $+,-,*$.

Unfortunately, some exercises want you to verify the ring axioms with super-artificially defined rings. For example, the set $R$ of pairs $(a,b)$ of integers $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with addition $(a,b)+(c,d) = (a+c,b+d)$, but multiplication $(a,b) *' (c,d) = (ac+2bd,ad+bc)$. You can spend pages with computations, or you learn the general construction of generated subrings and realize that the above ring is just $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ (the subring of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by $\sqrt{2}$) in disguise, where $(a,b)$ encodes $a+ b \sqrt{2}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a ring for trivial reasons, the same is true for $R$ without any necessary computations.

Answer (score 7):

It may possibly be easier to remember what axioms are missing with multiplication.

As in, multiplication has an identity element, and is associative, but does not have to be commutative, and doesn't need an inverse, whereas addition has all of these things.

That leaves left and right distributivity.  And the fact that left and right distributivity are called out separately may help you remember that multiplication doesn't have to be commutative.

Comment: You have listed the axioms for a **ring with identity** but the question asked about the axioms for a **ring**.

Comment: @bof Rings without 1? What kind of a heathen are you? ;)

Comment: @Stahl No heathen, I double-checked by looking up the definition of a ring in the Old Testament: Van der Waerden's *Modern Algebra*, Volume 1.

Comment: The OP asked about unital rings (because he refered to 8 axioms). That's why my answer also considers unital rings.

Comment: For what it's worth, [this guided my answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I guessed the OP was asking about **rings** because he referred to 4 axioms for addition (Closure, Associativity, Commutativity, Solvability) and 4 axioms for multiplication (Closure, Associativity, Left Distributivity, Right Distributivity). But counting axioms is an unreliable guide, because equivalent axiomatizations can have differing numbers of axioms.

Comment: "Closure" is not an axiom. The multiplication is *data*, not *property*. Your definition of an abelian group is also a bit unfortunate ("solvability").